# Multiplication of a set by a multiplicative subgroup of $ F^*_p $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, additive-combinatorics

Suppose that $ \Gamma \subset F^*_p $ (integers modulo a prime number $p$) is a multiplicative subgroup. $ A \subset F^*_p$ is a set and $ A $ is smaller than $ \Gamma $. Also

$$ A\Gamma = \{a\gamma: a \in A, \gamma \in \Gamma \} $$

is a set of products of every element of $ A $ by every element of $\Gamma$.

Is it true that $|A\Gamma| = |A|$?

Comment: No. Take $p=5$, $\Gamma=\{1,-1\}$ and $A=\{2\}$. Then $A\Gamma = \{2,-2\}$, so $|A|=1$, $|A\Gamma|=2$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin ahh, I was reading a paper where the author asserted that it's true for the (apparently) carefully selected set. Sorry, I got confused, and thank you for the quick response

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Do you want to post that as an answer so the question doesn't remain unanswered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. An easy example is to take $|A|=1$, because multiplication in $F^*$ is cancellative; then $|A\Gamma|=|\Gamma|$, which by assumption is strictly larger than $A$. Thus, for instance, in $\mathbb{F}_5$ you can take $\Gamma=\{1,-1\}$ and $A=\{2\}$.